# Entity Framework Core Scaffolding "Could not find type mapping for column with data type 'hierarchyid'. Skipping column"

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, scaffolding, hierarchyid

I'm experimenting with .net core, entity framework and sqlserver, i thought the hierarchyID is a perfect datatype for what i'm trying to model. But when i scaffolded the database, EFC was not able to map the hierarchy.

```
Could not find type mapping for column 'dbo.ingredient.hierarchy_id' with data type 'hierarchyid'. Skipping column.
Could not scaffold the primary key for 'dbo.ingredient'. The following columns in the primary key could not be scaffolded: hierarchy_id.
Unable to generate entity type for table 'dbo.ingredient'.
Could not find type mapping for column 'dbo.ingredient_location.ingredient_id' with data type 'hierarchyid'. Skipping column.
Could not find type mapping for column 'dbo.locations.location' with data type 'geography'. Skipping column.
Could not find type mapping for column 'dbo.pantry_ingredient.ingredient_id' with data type 'hierarchyid'. Skipping column.
```

Should I drop the idea to use that data type or there is a work around?

I looked for some solutions but all of them require to write the scaffolding by hand and i'm not confident enough at the moment to do so

Comment: hierarchyid doesn't seem well-supported by EF Core. See SO question and answers [Entity Framework Core hierarchyid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594409/entity-framework-core-hierarchyid) for some tips.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i decided to use a custom hierarchy by defining a parent id field

Answer (score 11):

you need to install nuget Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite for hanving support to geometry functionality.

Comment: thank you alessandro, but it was caused by the hierarchy id data type as well and that one could not be solved at the current version of entity framework that i'm using though

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem.
My project used all Microsoft libraries version 3.1.4 and MySQL.Data version 8.0.22
and MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore version 8.0.22
Luckily enough I had a very similar project build earlier which used
Microsoft libraries version 3.1.4 and MySQL.Data version 8.0.20
and MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore version 8.0.20
Once I switched back the MySQL libraries back to version 8.0.20
Scaffolding worked just fine.

I guess just conflicting libs or versions 8.0.22 have some bugs.

Comment: in my case I had problem with datetime data type

Comment: I had the same problem, I returned the version to 8.0.20 and it worked, is it a bug already identified? now i have found that version 8.0.20 maps the tinyint (1) type to byte and not to bool as in version 8.0.22, I will have to choose one and make corrections after scafold