# .NET Core 3.1 and SQL Server hierarchyid - multiple exceptions

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I work with SQL Server Db in my .Net Core 3.1 project and some stored procedures and views have hierarchyid types for parameters and data.

I use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` package. And when I try to read data with `SqlDataReader` I get the exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'. The system cannot find the file specified.

ok, I tried to use `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` as it suggests but this package is not .NET Standard and it doesn't work.

Also, I found `EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId` but when I use it I get:

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId' to type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.Server.IBinarySerialize'.

So how on Earth can one use HierarchyId type in .NET Core 3.1?

I'm planning to host this solution on linux.

## UPDATE

I do use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` 2.0 which is compatible with .NET Core. Also, I added then `EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId`, and I get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId' to type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.Server.IBinarySerialize'.

Here's the .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Helpers\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

No luck so far.

## UPDATE 2

This is the code where the exception is thrown:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = await detailsCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    details.Add(new HierarchyDetails
    {
      Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
      groupPath = reader.GetValue(1).ToString(), // <==== EXCEPTION
      name = reader.GetString(2),
      optionalData = reader.IsDBNull(3) ? null : reader.GetString(3)
    });
  }
}
```

And the table has the only row:

```
id  groupPath   culture name    optionalData
24  0x58        en-US   testing
```

Comment: `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=10.0.0.0` ... isn't that SQL Server 2008? SQL Server 2008 [finished Extended Support in 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4456242/end-of-support-for-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2008-r2).

Comment: Please update question with example code and place where you find this exception.

Comment: added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution at the moment to cast hierarchyid to NVARCHAR in all your queries:

```
... CAST(groupPath as NVARCHAR(4000)) as groupPath ...
```

and then use it as string.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message suggests that you use something which uses nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/10.50.1600.1 which is .NET Framework dll, not .NET Core.

You mention that you use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, please ensure that you use  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/ which is compatible with .NET Core.

In case of other errors please check also [Entity Framework Core hierarchyid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594409/entity-framework-core-hierarchyid)