# 'The entity type 'HierarchyId' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.'

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I used Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version 3.1.6 and .net core sdk 3.1

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Hierarchy;


public class Item
{
 
    public int ItemID{ get; set; }


    [Key]
    public HierarchyId ItemHID { get; set; }
}
```

Also, ItemHID is set primary key in Item SQL table. The build was successed but I'm getting the error in run time "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'HierarchyId' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.'". Have you any idea?

Comment: `HierarchyId` from `System.Data.Entity.Hierarchy` can't be used with EF Core - it is from EF6 extension library and can be used only with EF6. For EF Core see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594409/entity-framework-core-hierarchyid

Comment: I deleted "using System.Data.Entity.Hierarchy;" in  given code  and then I added  EntityFramework version 6.4.4 to project but HierarchyId is not recognized. Which namespace cover HierarchyId? @IvanStoev

Answer (score 0):

EF Core 8 now natively supports [HierarchyID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/hierarchyid?tabs=netcore-cli).

Add the below config when you configure DbContext(s).

```
options.UseSqlServer(
    connectionString,
    x => x.UseHierarchyId());
```